# "Keyerror" - Iterating through each element in Dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, loops, if-statement, iteration

Trying to iterate through each element in a 2D Dataframe so that if the value for a column has changed from previous row to 1, that value would be left intact, but otherwise the value would always become 0.

Tried the code below, however I get a "Keyerror:0" or "Keyerror:1" depending on what I define as range start. Any ideas to fix it or do it in another way?

```
for R in range(1, signal_data.shape[0]):
      for C in range(1, signal_data.shape[1]):
                    if signal_data[C][R] - signal_data[C][R-1] == 1:
                          signal_data[C][R] = 1
                    else:
                            signal_data[C][R] = 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not call a pandas dataframe column by its id like that.
Either use the real column name (you can get them using `df.columns` and store it in a list)
or use [loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html)

Seeing your code, you may consider using a `numpy.array` instead of a `pandas.DataFrame`

Comment: Thanks Grall! I made a list of of the column names and iterate the dimension using that, and looks like it works.

Comment: Oh and btw, will also look into using numpy.array, not so familiar with that.

Comment: Glad to know you solved this :)
Definitely have a look at numpy, it is a must when working with arrays in python !